# why do i get TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

for the following segment of code I seem to be getting an error but i don't understand where the 'module' data type comes from and why it isn't iterable

```
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, shortestLength=-1, path=[]):
  path = path + [start]
  if start == end:
    return path
  if start not in graph:
    return None
  shortest = None
  for node in graph[start]:
    if node not in path:
      if shortestLength == -1 or len(path) < (shortestLength - 1):
        newpath = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, shortestLength, path)
```

it returns this error

```
line 11, in find_shortest_path
    if start not in graph:
TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable
```

Comment: You're passing a module name instead of a graph as the first argument when you call `find_shortest_path`. Please post a [mre]

Comment: @Barmar i have added some code to better help understand the error

Comment: You still haven't shown how you call the function. Where does the original `graph` value come from?